# How to calculate internal rate of return [beginner]

Tags: bonds, rate-of-return

I am an informatics student who was given an assignment to do with finance and we're not very financially literate.

We are asked to theoretically build a platform to mimic bond exchanges. As part of this platform, we are told we need to calculate an **internal rate of return**.

You can see the rate of return formula we were provided here:[image]

Now, assuming we have a bond whose details are as follows: the bond is priced at $100 with a term of 5 years. The coupon/interest rate is 5%, and the frequency of payments is annual.

Using the assumptions above, we can infer that the payout would be $125 (paid in four instalments of $5 and a final instalment of $105).

From what I understand and what we were told (and please do correct me if I'm wrong), the **internal rate of return** represents the point at which inflation becomes too high for an investor to make a profit on the bond.

I have a function that already calculates the payout assuming inflation (for example, assuming an inflation of 5% using the bond described above, the payout would be $99.99).

We are told that the internal rate of return for this bond is **0.0432** (i.e. **4.32%**). What I do not understand is how to get to that number.

So, in summary:

I have the details at Point A (price = $100, term = 5 years, coupon = 5%, frequency = annual) and I have the number I want to get to at Point B (internal rate of return = 4.32%).

I just want to know how to get from point A to point B.

Comment: The price at any given moment and the redemption value, the value paid at maturity, are almost never the same.

Answer (score 2):

Either there is some more information you have not given us or the answer you have been provided is incorrect.  The internal rate of return based on this information is 5%.

The internal rate of return is the rate which, when used to discount the payments of a bond, makes the present value of the bond payments equal to its price.  Therefore in your case, it's the r that solves

0 = -100 + 5/(1+r) + 5/(1+r)^2 + 5/(1+r)^3 + 5/(1+r)^4 + 105/(1+r)^5

In the context of a default-free bond the IRR is the same as the *Yield to Maturity*. You will need to use an optimizer in general, but for an annual bond that has just paid a coupon and is priced at par, the IRR or YTM will be equal to the coupon rate.

Is there perhaps a chance that the bond will default?  Does the first payment come a year from today?  Is today's price really 100? Any other complications you have not mentioned?